# SQLiteOpenHelper How to update and delete data from table?

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, sql-delete, sqliteopenhelper

I created a database for students with fields Name, surname, marks and I did insert and view sucessfully 
but I don't know how to do Update and Delete.
Please help here I want to do update and delete based on ID.

Answer (score 3):

In DatabaseHandler class,

for `update`:

```
public long update(String id,String name,String surname,String marks) {

    ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,surname);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,marks);
    return mDb.update(TABLENAME, contentValues,"ID=?",new String[] {id});
}
```

For Delete Use:

```
public long delete(String ID){
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    return mDb.delete(TABLENAME,"ID=?",new String[]{ID});
}
```

Comment: Its simple use to update `myDB.update(id,name,surname,marks);` for delete `myDB.delete(ID);`

Comment: we can't use this line  in mainactivity??myDB.update(updatename.getText().toString(),updatesurname.getText().toString(),updatemark.getText().toString());

Comment: Yes you can these and all basic things [refer](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: it shows me error on this line updatename.getText().toString(),updatesurname.getText(‌​).toString(),updatemark.getText().toString()

Comment: then check the datatype and number of  arguments your passing to  updates are same.